# Is it an anti-pattern for Swift functions that take in a sender to have a label for that parameter?

Tags: anti-patterns, parameters, swift-language, labels

This is something I see all over Cocoa:

```
func someAction(_ sender: Any)
```

which is called like:

```
someAction(someObject)
```

This can be very confusing to me. The infamous example is in `NSView` subclasses:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

Despite this being standard Swift syntax for printing to the console, in an `NSView`, this will open the printer dialog, claiming the sender is the String `"Hello, World!"`. So, in my code I started doing this:

```
func someAction(sender: Any)
```

but I fear that the fact I see *none* of this in Cocoa means it's an anti-pattern. **Is that the case, or am I in the right?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. Pure Swift probably doesn't use the `_`, and rather prefers `sender`, or a label and then a variable name. The use of the `_` all over Swift code translated from Cocoa is because that's just how the Obj-C gets translated to Swift 3 thanks to this change. [Swift 3 rationale behind naming](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/e4328889a9643100177aef19f6f428855c5d0cf2/proposals/0046-first-label.md).

Perhaps, if you are working closely with Obj-C and/or Cocoa and want to keep your naming conventions the same, you could use the `_`, but it is certainly not required. [Here is an example straight from Apple's docs of acceptable Swift 3 code that does not use the _](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID59):

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

    override init?(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        let action = #selector(MyViewController.tappedButton)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func tappedButton(sender: UIButton?) {
        print("tapped button")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```